# Why can I access struct fields by a variable and the reference to that variable in the same way? (Rust)

Tags: rust, reference, borrow-checker

[image]

If I print x.passwd, I will get 234
If I print y.passwd, I will get 234 too, But how is that possible since y = &x (essentially storing the address of x), shouldnt I be dereferencing in order to access passwd like (*y).passwd?

[image]

I was solving a leetcode problem and they were accessing a node's val field directly by the reference without dereferencing and that made me more confused about references.

On Left hand size, we have Option<Box> while on the right we have &Option<Box>, How can we perform Some(node) = node

PS: I Hope someone explains with a memory diagram of what is actually happening. And if anyone has good resources to understand references and borrowing, Please Let me know, I have been referring the docs and Lets Get Rusty youtube channel but still references are little confusing for me.

Comment: The value will be 234 according to question instead of 123, Sorry for the confusion

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2):

In Rust, the `.` operator will automatically dereference as necessary to find something with the right name. In `y.passwd`, `y` is a reference, but references don't have any named fields, so the compiler tries looking at the type of the referent — `Cred` — and does find the field named `passwd`.

The same thing works with methods, but there's some more to it — in addition to dereferencing, the compiler will also try *adding* an `&` to find a matching method. That way you don't have to write the awkward `(&foo).bar()` just to call a method that takes `&self`, similar to how you've already found that you don't have to write `(*y).passwd`.

In general, you rarely (but not never) have to worry about whether or not something is a reference, when using `.`.